# "Collapse" table to eliminate null values

Tags: sql

I have a product that allows creation of custom fields in the GUI.  I created three fields: System Ship Date, System Warranty End Date, and System Warranty Notes.  Sadly, the system populates these as rows, not columns.

Example:

```
Machine_GroupID      | agentGuid | fieldName                |  fieldValue
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
systemABC.companyABC | 57537921  | System Ship Date         | 1/1/1900
systemABC.companyABC | 57537921  | System Warranty End Date | 1/1/1950
systemABC.companyABC | 57537921  | System Warranty Notes    | Test notes
system123.companyABC | 48394844  | System Ship Date         | 1/1/1900
system123.companyABC | 48394844  | System Warranty End Date | 1/1/1950
system123.companyABC | 48394844  | System Warranty Notes    | Test notes
systemXYZ.companyABC | 99948403  | System Ship Date         | 1/1/1900
systemXYZ.companyABC | 99948403  | System Warranty End Date | 1/1/1950
systemXYZ.companyABC | 99948403  | System Warranty Notes    | Test notes
```

I need to return System Ship Date as a column, System Warranty End Date as a column, and System Warranty Notes as a column.  If I use a CASE WHEN statement:

```
CASE WHEN sim.fieldName = 'System Ship Date' 
     THEN sim.fieldValue END AS 'System Ship Date',
CASE WHEN sim.fieldName = 'System Warranty End Date' 
     THEN sim.fieldValue END AS 'System Warranty End Date',
CASE WHEN sim.fieldName = 'System Warranty Notes' 
     THEN sim.fieldValue END AS 'System Warranty Notes'
```

**The data appears thusly on a per-computer basis:**

**header1 header2 header3**
data1 NULL NULL
NULL data2 NULL
NULL NULL data3

**I need it to appear like this:**

**header1 header2 header3**
data1 data2 data3

I thought I could somehow use MAX() but I'm a novice and it's beyond me.  Alternatively I know I could create a temporary table but I don't know that either.  I've searched extensively online and on stack, but that's as far as I could get is the CASE WHEN statement.

Comment: Sounds like you need a so-called Pivot table, but not every RDMS supports that feature. Which is yours?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MS SQL:

```
SELECT
  Machine_GroupID, agentGuid, "System Ship Date", "System Warranty End Date", "System Warranty Notes"
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    Machine_GroupID, agentGuid, fieldName, MAX(fieldValue) AS Value
  FROM
    sim
  GROUP BY
    Machine_GroupID, agentGuid, fieldName
  ) AS X
PIVOT
  (MAX(Value) FOR fieldName IN ("System Ship Date", "System Warranty End Date", "System Warranty Notes")) AS Y
```

The `GROUP BY` clause isn't strictly necessary in your case, but without it `PIVOT` sometimes returns extraneous rows, rather like your first table.

Answer (score 7):

Why not SELF JOIN? Keep it simpler still...

```
SELECT
   s1.Machine_GroupID, s1.agentGuid,
   s1.fieldValue, s2.fieldValue, s3.fieldValue
FROM
   sim s1
   JOIN sim s2 ON s1.Machine_GroupID = s2.Machine_GroupID
   JOIN sim s3 ON s1.Machine_GroupID = s3. Machine_GroupID
WHERE
   s1.fieldName = 'System Ship Date' AND
   s2.fieldName = 'System Warranty End Date' AND
   s2.fieldName = 'System Warranty Notes'
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `LEFT JOIN`s, unless it's guaranteed that all Machine_Groups have all three fields.  Also, unless such a guarantee exists, you'll need `sim` four times: once as a base, then self-joined three times, once for each field.

Comment: Great answer. I had the same problem -- trying to pivot rows without using an aggregate (I wanted to keep all the different values without pick a max, min, avg, etc.), and this did the trick.